# SQL Cumulative Sum not showing when group by values are missing

Tags: sql, window, amazon-redshift, partition

I have some monthly data as below:

```
Month     | Category          | Monthly Value
2020-07-01| Food              | 1
2020-07-01| Entertainment     | 4
2020-08-01| Entertainment     | 2
2020-09-01| Entertainment     | 1
```

I want to calculate the cumulative sum for each Category and get the result as below:

```
Month       |  Category     | Cumulative Sum
2020-07-01  |  Food         |   1
2020-08-01  |  Food         |   1
2020-09-01  |  Food         |   1
2020-07-01  | Entertainment |   4
2020-08-01  | Entertainment |   6
2020-09-01  | Entertainment |   7
```

I'm writing the window sum query as below:

```
    SELECT
      month
    , category
    , sum("monthly value") OVER (PARTITION BY "category" ORDER BY "month" ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS "Cumulative Sum"
    from (
select date_trunc('month', daily_date) as month, category, sum(daily_value) as "monthly value"
from sample_table 
group by date_trunc('month', daily_date) as month, category)
```

But, I'm getting as follows:

```
Month           |  Category     | Cumulative Sum
    2020-07-01  |  Food         |   1
    2020-07-01  | Entertainment |   4
    2020-08-01  | Entertainment |   6
    2020-09-01  | Entertainment |   7
```

Why is "Food" Category's Cumulative Sum not showing up for the months of `2020-08-01` and `2020-09-01`? How can I make the result be displayed as expected (shown in the 2nd table).

I'm using Redshift btw.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select m.month, c.category, t.monthly_value,
       sum(t.monthly_value) over (partition by c.category order by m.month) as running_monthly_value
from (select distinct month from t) m cross join
     (select distinct category from t) c left join
     t
     on t.month = m.month and t.category = c.category;
```